# Eliminate for loop when indexing into array

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I have two arrays:
`vals` has shape (N,m) where N is ~1 million, and m is 3. The values are floats
I have another array `indices` with shape `(N,4)`. All values in `indices` are row indices in `vals`. (Additionally, unlike the example here, every row of `indices` contains unique values.).

```
import numpy as np
from random import randrange

# set up the arrays for this test example (no need to improve this)
N = 9
vals = np.array(list(range(3*N))).reshape((N,3))
indices = np.array([randrange(N) for n in range(4*N)]).reshape((N,4))
```

I would like replace the following for loop when creating the array `aug`

```
# form an augmented matrix by indexing into vals using rows from indices
aug = np.stack([vals[indices[x]] for x in range(N)])

# compute a mean along axis=1 of aug
aug.mean(axis=1)
```

The broader context for the question is `vals` contains numeric data for particles distributed in 3D. `indices` is generated using a nearest neighbor search on the spatial positions of the particles (using `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`) . I would like to average the numeric data over the nearest neighbors. As I have ~1 million particles, a for-loop is quite slow.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. Please read about how to ask a good question and try to post a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") so we can better help you.

Comment: @itprorh66, there is a MRE in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually can replace the entire `aug = ...` line with

```
aug = vals[indices]
```

That will produce the same result:

```
np.array_equal(
    np.stack([vals[indices[x]] for x in range(N)]),
    vals[indices]
)
# True
```